# What's the weapon Nadia Fierro/Baldwin uses in Counterpart S01E08 to kill the guy in his flat?

Tags: props, counterpart

In episode 8 of the first series of *Counterpart*, Nadia Fierro uses a kind of automatic strangling device, she puts it over the head of her victim, he struggles and dies. Is this original to the series or is it known from somewhere else? It is similar to the "bolito" from *The Counselor*, but not the same, as *Counterpart*'s version doesn't seem to be electric.

Comment: I think the word you're after is [Garotte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garrote).  I don't see any mention of it being anything other than a mechanically operated device.

Comment: Either that, or a (metallic) cable tie, as this one seems to work like one, allowing the user to pull it fast and just let go. @Snow Mind turning that into an answer?

Comment: Looked and sounded like a cable snare used for trapping. They stay once tightened.